# Kendo with Angular2: How to display custom message when there are no records available in Kendo Grid

Tags: kendo-grid, kendo-ui-angular2

I am using Kendo Grid with Angular 2. If there are no data, then I am getting No records available message which is the default one which comes with Kendo Grid. I wanted to customise the message. I tried [NoRecords]={"Some message"}; inside KendoGrid html tag, but its not working.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This can be achieved by nesting the `kendo-grid-message` component within the `kendo-grid`.

```
<kendo-grid [data]="[]">
  <kendo-grid-messages
    noRecords="There are no items to display.">
  </kendo-grid-messages>
</kendo-grid>
```

Make sure you are using the **correct capitalization** for the inputs (camel case).

For a more in-depth description on that topic please refer to the [globalization documentation](https://www.telerik.com/kendo-angular-ui/components/grid/globalization/) .

A list of available inputs for the `kendo-grid-messages` component can be found [here](https://www.telerik.com/kendo-angular-ui/components/grid/api/CustomMessagesComponent/).